# continuos(2-3 seconds interval) to apache server through javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets

I developed one web application in which i am using AJAX polling to the server page i.e. servlet and getting the updated data after every 2-3 seconds ad its working fine, will 60-70 concurrent users pinging to the server for data affects the server load much? Will it make the server crash?

My Servlets are getting data from web service and I'm getting everything fine. But dont have much knowledge about the server load.

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Ars

Answer (score 1):

For push channels I suggest you use

1) A designed library like http://socket.io/ which uses WebSockets and falls back to long polling

2) You do not use Apache which has not been designed to handle this kind of traffic, but use a web server which supports continuous streaming of events better. Eventually with Apache you will have scalability and other problems.